# Are there disadvantages to setting up unit or integration tests in Eclipse as a separate project?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing

I'm currently working on a project using Eclipse where the unit and integration tests are in one project that also contains the DAO and service layer, and there is another project that includes the Web interface. The Web interface contains the Spring configuration files, and instead of duplicating them for the tests in the DAO project, I want to reference the ones that already exist. However, as I started thinking about it, if this is possible, why not just move them into their own project completely and setup project dependencies. Has anyone done this, and do you have an example of this setup, or can you provide some roadblocks you encountered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead with this approach, and it doesn't appear to be causing any issues so far. One of our projects has a (classpath) dependency on the other, but the third test project is able to manage that with some setup and configuration.